# git merge or rebase for stale branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I've got the master branch and another branch let's say B which is a fork of the master. 
The B branch was experimental and underwent a lot of modifications but was left stale for a year. 
Master branch has moved a lot forward during that year with countless commits.

But now the situation wants the B branch merged into the master one.
Which strategy is best in this situation, a git merge or rebase ?

Comment: Careful; the term *fork* is most likely a misnomer, here. You probably mean that branch `B` *stems from* `master`, or something like that.

Comment: Are there other people with local copies of branch B?  Do you care about preserving history?  If you answer no/no then rebase.

Comment: People with local copies of B is only a concern if you are merging master into B and updating B. As I read your question, that was not the case. You are looking to move master ahead with the commits from B.  Therefore if it were me, I would rebase B from master, address the merge conflicts, and go from there.

`git fetch -p`

`git checkout B`

`git rebase origin/master`

if there are merge conflicts: `git mergetool`

If I didn't want all of the changes from B, then I would cherry-pick commits from B into master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward merge may be problematic if there's a lot of work to be merged, and you want to do it progressively (in order to test the results).

You could try to repeatedly rebase to newer versions of the master, until you finally reach the tip. Note that you don't need to rebase B itself (in case it's public) -  simply make a copy of B and rebase it.

Another tool that is worth knowing about in these situations is git's [`rerere`](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/08/rerere.html)